# Python script with cron only finished the first loop

Tags: python, cron

I have a python script which runs a ***for*** loop. I made it executable and put it in a **cron** job.

It posts a few tweets on twitter. For each loop, it sleeps a few seconds with random times.

However, it appears it only runs the very first loop and then stops. Every time, I only got ONE tweet. I could not figure out why.

Here is the core part of the code.

```
def post_message(url):

    d = parse(url)
    entries = d.entries

    for entry in entries:
        str = entry.title
        tweet(str)

        t = random.randint(start, stop)         
        time.sleep(t)
```

This is how I set it in cron.

```
0 23 * * * /home/demo/post_message.py
```

It only post the very first one and then stops. I am wondering if the time.sleep function stops the rest loops in cron?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you run the program manually via the shell? This way you can tell if it's crashing after the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried to run this python script from shell?
2. Is there any exception (Like you posted too frequently led the script to a 403 page which keeps the function from finding any appropriate html element) generated in 2nd tweet() function?